# Android developer Json & Pubnub

Tags: android, json, gson, pubnub

Hi I wrote a code to publish a json with the Pubnub Channel:

```
pubnubMessage = new Pubnub("demo", "demo");     
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(id.map);
            map = mapFragment.getMap();
            LocationManager = new MyLocation(this);
            LocationManager.initLocation();
            callback = new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onNewLocation(Location location, String name) {
                    // *****sending the json string*****
                    JsonSendLocation jsonsendlocation = new JsonSendLocation();
                    jsonsendlocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
                    jsonsendlocation.setLongtitude(location.getLongitude());
                    jsonsendlocation.setUsername(preferencesUtils.getName(
                            getApplicationContext(), preName, key));

                    Gson json = new Gson();
                    String jsonString = json.toJson(jsonsendlocation,
                            JsonSendLocation.class);

                    JSONObject ff;
                    try {
                        ff = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                        publishToPubnub(MY_CHANNEL, ff);                    
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Now i want to recieve the json object from my Pubnub channel , I wrote:

```
Pubnub recieve = new Pubnub("demo", "demo");    
        try {
            recieve.subscribe("MyChannel", new com.pubnub.api.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void successCallback(String arg0, Object arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        } catch (PubnubException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can I get my json from my channel?

Comment: I assume you are asking what is passed into the successCallback's parameters: String arg0, Object arg1. The docs that Geremy pointed you to have arguments with more clear names, but just for quick reference for all, here is what it looks like:

Comment: public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
          System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
                     + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
      }

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use one instance of a`Pubnub` object, just declare it as an instance variable and instantiate it in `onCreate`. Then you can publish and subscribe using this same Pubnub Object.

```
private Pubnub mPubNub;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.mPubNub = new Pubnub(Constants.PUBLISH_KEY, Constants.SUBSCRIBE_KEY);
    subscribe();
    // publish();
}
```

Now, when you are receiving your object in the `successCallback`, Java type casting is fully valid. I like to check using `instanceof` so my app doesn't crash if the message is invalid for some reason.

```
public void subscribe(){
    Callback callbacks = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
            if (message instanceof JSONObject){
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) message;
                // Handle JSON
            } else if (message instanceof String){
                String str = (String) message;
                // Handle String
            }
            Log.d("PUBNUB", "Channel: " + channel + " Msg: " + message.toString());
        }
    };
    try {
        this.mPubNub.subscribe("MyChannel", callbacks);
    } catch (PubnubException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any other issues!